# Display value change from DB on webstie

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, arduino

I have an arduino with an sensor (accelerametor) it sends a single value to my DB. this value increments  by 1 with movements.

I managed to display this value in my console log. but it doesnt update when it increments. I did have a function which did this but it required user interaction from the client side.

I want to know if it is possible one way or another to have this value change on the webbage when it does in the DB?

Here is my code:

Javascript:

```
//gets the value from the DB and displays it on my webpage
firebase.database().ref('Reps').once('value').then (function(snapshot){
    WemosGet = snapshot.val().Value;
    document.getElementById("progressList").innerHTML=WemosGet;
    console.log(WemosGet);

})
```

HTML:

```
<p>Repetitions left: <br><strong id="progressList"></strong></p></strong></p>
```

What I tried previously, with with user onaction:

```
output.innerHTML = slider.value
    update=()=>{
        output.innerHTML = slider.value; 
        // Display the default slider value
        console.log(slider.value)
        setAmount = slider.value;
    }

// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
slider.addEventListener('input', update);
```

So, I want to have it update when say for instance the eventlistener detects that the value has been changes(incremented). Would this work in a similar fashion? What would be the best approad for this? IM at a loss.

Answer (score 1):

Use `on('value')` instead of `once('value')` to attach a listener to a query so that it gets invoked every time there is a change of data in that query.  `once()` just fetches data a single time.  I suggest reading the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data) to lean how that works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX with timed interval to query the database (or Websocket messaging to update the page which requires more resources to implement).